# How can I cancel Drag and Drop operation in Java/Swing programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I am just wondering if it's possible to I cancel "Drag and Drop" operation in Java/Swing programmatically? So the effect would be similar to if the user pressed the "ESC" key?

I was expecting `DragSourceDragEvent` or `DragSourceContext` to have a `cancelDrag()` method, similar to `DropTargetDragEvent` which has `acceptDrag()` and `rejectDrag()` methods (both of which does not do what I want).

I am missing something?

Comment: This claims that it is not possible: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4502185 is it true? Surely not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed I tried several ways of doing this and nothing worked I also tried using the Robot class to press escape :)

Appears it is not currently possible to abort this with the current API.